# Simple RESTtEasy example doesn't work

Tags: java, resteasy

I tried to write a simple RESTEasy example to see how it works. I found info here:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/integrate-jackson-with-resteasy/
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/

It is really simple and I understood how it works from another Restful example that is similar and works just fine.

```
@Path("/person")
public class PersonResource {
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonResource.class);

    private final static String FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
    private final static String LAST_NAME = "lastName";
    private final static String EMAIL = "email";

    private Person person = new Person(1, "Sample", "Person", "sample_person@jerseyrest.com");

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String respondAsReady() {
        return "Entered PersonResource";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Person getProductInJSON() {
        return person;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("sample")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getSamplePerson() {
        LOG.debug("getSamplePerson()");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("Person First Name:", person.getFirstName());
            jsonObject.put("Person Last Name:", person.getLastName());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            LOG.debug("jsonObect.put failed");
        }

        String result = "jsonObject:" + jsonObject;
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }
}
```

My web.xml :

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>com.restexample.PersonResource</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My pom.xml:

```xml
<!-- RESTEasy-->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I try http://localhost:8080/rest/person/sample or any other path to acces the methods there is a blank screen. I DON'T have 404 NOT FOUND! Just blank screen. (I'm using TomCat). Can anyone help me?

Comment: well, like in those examples i want the info to be printed in browser. If i try [http://localhost:8080/rest/person] I expect  "Entered PersonResource" to be printed I don't have any exceptions in server logs.

Comment: Do your debug log messages appear? Have you stepped through your program using a debugger?

Comment: My debug messages do not appear in log file

Comment: Is your application set as Tomcat's root context? It looks like you are skipping the app context and going straight to /rest.

Comment: the default link is [http://localhost:8080/] so I guess the url is fine . The method is never called when i access the url( debugger). This example with jersey worked just fine [http://avilyne.com/?p=105]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. In my pom.xml I had this:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This listener is creating an application context. Nothing wrong until now. 
The ResteasyBootstrap that is defined in web.xml provides as well a context:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Because both listeners are providing a different context, the URL doesn't return a 404 NOT FOUND, neither the good result.

***The solution:***

Remove the listener ContextLoaderListener in the xml and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@GET
@Path("sample")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getSamplePerson() {
    LOG.debug("getSamplePerson()");
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(person).build();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work :( and another weird thing is that my log file is empty. Even if I use the logger , LOG.debug does not produce any output in the log file

Comment: Try and debug your Tomcat and set a breakpoint in `getSamplePerson()`to see if it's even called when you open the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this in your web.xml :

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>
```

> https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.1.GA/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html

Comment: That wasn't the cause :(